# Why Term.Text returns invalid data for Numericfields in Lucene.Net even though it supposed to convert accrodingly?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I was trying to return all values in order to use them later for facets as following:

```
TermEnum termsEnum = reader.Terms(new Term(groupByField, string.Empty));
```

But as soon as I added a filed like this:

```
NumericField tempNumericField = new NumericField("price", Field.Store.YES, true);
```

`Term.Text` started to return wrong data for the price field.

Is there a way to return all date for both Field and NumericFields?

Answer (score 1):

`NumericFields` are stored in an encoded form (allows for correct ordering, ranges etc).

Try using `NumericUtils.PrefixCodedToInt` (or the appropriate method for long etc)